# How can I echo a value from this object?

Tags: php, arrays, object

When I print my object this is what it looks like:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => post_impressions
                    [period] => lifetime
                    [values] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [value] => 4448
                                )

                        )

                    [title] => Lifetime Post Total Impressions
                    [description] => Lifetime: The number of impressions of your Page post. (Total Count)
                    [id] => 367712570004555_1292256510883485/insights/post_impressions/lifetime
                )

        )

    [paging] => stdClass Object
        (
            [previous] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/3677125700055_129256510883485/insights?access_token=EAACEdEse0cBANjKErkMLhCgmZBBrgLn8KtZBW2d6JbWz7sZAivld67JxvP8MqyZCs9xg3Bh11lzETwd64LAPp3zbstu8ELFZC8HOwYyxckqJ60WQcVL1FqB3iy5L3oRCsFSQzPx2B53WZCMwRTSGKyqXe8uFGPhMZBnFYsZCFHyaUA7MzHGgcqIYxsjAlJomYrOMZCqo6PwZDZD&metric=post_impressions&since=1505890800&until=1506063600
            [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/36771257004555_1292256583485/insights?access_token=EAACEdEose0cBANjLn8KtZBW2d6JbWz7sZAivld67JxvP8MqyZCs9xg3Bh11lzETOwd64LIpAPp3zbstu8ELFZC8HOwYyxcVL1FqB3iy5L3oRCsFSQzPx2B53WZCMwRTSGKyqXe8uFGPhMZBnFYsZCFHyaUA7MzHGgcqIYxsjAlJomYrOMZCqo6PwZDZD&metric=post_impressions&since=150626400&until=150409200
        )

)
```

How can I echo `[value]`?

I tried

`echo $insights[0]->data->values->value;` But this gives me a `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/studione/public_html/includes/facebook.php on line 83`

I also tried: `echo $insights->data->values->value;` but this shows nothing, not even an error.

Comment: why don't you convert your object into an array?

Comment: data is already in array     you can check this $insights->data[0]->values[0]->value it will give you value 4448 or for title $insights->data[0]->title

Comment: You can also use foreach() to parse the object and access values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo $insights->data[0]->values[0]->value;
```

Answer (score 8):

`data` is an array, `values` is an array too. If you want to output an element you have to specify the correct index of those arrays:

```
echo $insights->data[N]->values[M]->value;
```

Where N and M are the indexes of the arrays inside the object.

Comment: I feel this to be a better answer since it is properly explained, IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're missing out the zero, try wrapping it:

```
<?php  $insights->data->values->{0}->value;?>
```